# Calculate relative average and Lift for a group of data in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, average, window-functions

I have a data table that looks like this:

| Shop | Region | Waste% | AvgRegionWaste | Lift |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | CA | 10 | 15 (30/2) | 10/15 |
| b | CA | 20 | 15 (30/2) | 20/15 |
| c | LA | 32 | 37 (74/2) | 32/37 |
| d | LA | 42 | 37 (74/2) | 42/37 |

I am striving to calculate the last two columns *AvgRegionWaste* and *Lift*.

I tried the following approach (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55933005/10623444)):

```sql
SELECT avg(waste over (partition by Region order by Shop rows between unbounded preceding and current row) AS rolling_avg
FROM my_table
GROUP BY Shop, Region
```

But it doesn't seem to do the trick. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression that you need for the column `AvgRegionWaste` is:

```
AVG(waste) OVER (PARTITION BY Region)
```

and the query should be:

```
SELECT *,
       ROUND(AVG(waste) OVER (PARTITION BY Region), 2) AvgRegionWaste,
       ROUND(Waste / AVG(waste) OVER (PARTITION BY Region), 2) Lift
FROM my_table;
```

You can adjust the rounding of the returned values as you wish.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=872cdaac9ae046de738cbe7827f3f313).

Comment: Thanks a lot @forpas. Accepted and upvoted your answer. Kudos!